# Login Api AdWords in PHP (Codeigniter) without auth.ini

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, google-ads-api

I'm developing an app in php with codeigniter that needs to connect to Adwords, and I have a lot of questions...

First of all, I have a test account and I don't know if i'm connecting properly, because I don't know what I have to put as developerToken, clientId and defaultServer. Which is the correct one?

```
 $username = "my_email@gmail.com";
 $password = "my_password";

 //Developer Token options
 $developerToken_1 = "E2SGs1l7gEWWdCfeYSO4oA"; //It's not my real token..
 $developerToken_2 = "my_email@gmail.com++USD";

 $user = new AdWordsUser(null, $username, $password, $developerToken);

 //Default Servers
    //Option 1
      $user->SetDefaultServer("https://adwords.google.com/");
    //Option 2
      $user->SetDefaultServer("https://adwords-sandbox.google.com");                          
    //Option 3
      $user->SetDefaultServer("https://sandbox.google.com"); 

  //Client ID
    //Option 1
      $user->SetClientId('client_id_1+my_email@gmail.com');
    //Option 2
      $user->SetClientId('1234567890');
```

I think that I have to use the adwords version v201306

```
$campaignService = $user->GetService('CampaignService', 'v201306');
```

If I use "https://adwords.google.com/" as Server, I recieve:

```
Uncaught exception 'OAuth2Exception' with message '{
 "error" : "invalid_client"
}'
```

With the others servers, I recieve:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message:
   SoapClient::SoapClient(https://sandbox.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201306/CampaignService?wsdl): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Filename: Lib/AdsSoapClient.php
```

or

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message:
   SoapClient::SoapClient(https://adwords-sandbox.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201306/CampaignService?wsdl): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Filename: Lib/AdsSoapClient.php
```

What should I do? I've read a lot in too many webs and I don't know how can I solve it

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Nobody can help me???

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can find info (including the service endpoint url) about using the Analytics API as a test account here: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/test-accounts

Secondly, the readme states to use the following method to set your service:

```
$campaignService = $user->getCampaignService('v201306', 'https://adwords.google.com');
```

Lastly it seems the parameters you are using to initial the AdWordsUser object are a bit off, the readme also states the following:

```
$user = new AdWordsUser(NULL, NULL, NULL, $developerToken,
     $applicationToken, $userAgent, $clientCustomerId, NULL, NULL,
     $oauth2Info);
```